# How to disable whitespace: normal in jquery-ui css file but only for IE?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

In IE11, for some reason I see bullet points on jQuery UI tabs. They disappear as soon as I click on the tab, and appear when I reload the page. Screenshot below:

[image]

This doesn't happen in Firefox. Using the debugger, I found that switching off a `white-space: normal` rule in the "Computed" section of the IE debugger in a loaded css (jquery-ui.css) removes all the bullets. Screenshot of that part from the debugger below:

[image]

How can I disable this rule only for IE?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried just setting `list-style: none;` on that class?

Comment: @gaynorvader yes, and it did not fix the issue. I tried `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {

    list-style: none;
}`

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense. In your screen shot, the `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav` stylings are struck through. This suggest they are being over ridden by another styling that loads later. We need to see more details or to setup a test in jsfiddle.net. How can I replicate this in IE?

Comment: @Twisty They are both actually `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li` (screen cut off the rest in the screenshot) and the first one was not struck through until I unchecked `white-space` normal. When I check it back, the strike-through disappears, but the bullets don't reappear.

Comment: I fixed it based on the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303853/jquery-tabs-bullet-points-appear-next-to-tabs-looking-to-not-have-them-appear